# Assistance needed with generic types - type cannot be used as a type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have come across a slight issue with my class design and I am having trouble with dealing with it. Having searched the web to no avail I am hoping someone here would be kind enough to point me in the right direction. I have posted the entire code so in theory, should be able to do a simple copy and paste in VS and visualise the error.

Thanks in advance, Onam.

Full error:
***The type 'Complainant' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Person'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Complainant' to 'ObjectFactory'.***

```
#region : Complainant :
public class Complainant : Person<Complainant>
{
    #region Properties...

    #region ComplainantId
    public Int64 ComplainantId { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region IsApproachable
    public bool IsApproachable { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Constructors...
    public Complainant()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods...

    #region Load
    public void Load(Int64 objectId)
    {
        base.Hydrate(objectId);
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion
}
#endregion

#region : Person :
public class Person<T> : ObjectFactory<T>
{
    #region Properties...

    #region PersonId
    public Int64 PersonId { get; protected set; }
    #endregion

    #region DOB
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Email
    public string Email { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Forename
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Fullname
    public string Fullname { get { return Forename + " " + Surname; } }
    #endregion

    #region HomeTel
    public string HomeTel { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Initials
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Mobile
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Surname
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region WorkTel
    public string WorkTel { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Person()
    {
    }
    #endregion
}
#endregion

#region : Property :
public class Property
{
    #region Properties...

    #region Inherits
    [XmlAttribute("Inherits")]
    public string Inherits { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region IsPrimaryKey
    [XmlAttribute("IsPrimaryKey")]
    public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Name
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Constructors...

    public Property(string name, bool isPrimaryKey)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.IsPrimaryKey = isPrimaryKey;
    }

    public Property()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods


    #endregion
}
#endregion

#region : ObjectFactory :
public class ObjectFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    #region Members...
    static Expression<Func<T>> __x = () => new T();
    static Func<T> __function = __x.Compile();
    static Dictionary<Type, List<Property>> __cache = new Dictionary<Type, List<Property>>();
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ObjectFactory()
    {
        Type _type = typeof(T);

        if (!__cache.ContainsKey(_type))
        {
            __cache.Add(_type, Deserialize(_type.Name));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    #region Build
    public static T Build()
    {
        return __function();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Deserialize
    private List<Property> Deserialize(string objectName)
    {
        XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Property>));
        using (Stream _stream = File.OpenRead(String.Format(@"C:\_XMLFiles\{0}.xml", objectName)))
        {
            return (List<Property>)_serializer.Deserialize(_stream);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Hydrate
    protected void Hydrate(Int64 objectId)
    {
        List<Property> _properties = new List<Property>();

        if (__cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out _properties))
        {
            object[] o = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                string s = pi.Name;
                //if (pi.Name == name)
                //{
                    //pi.SetValue(this, value, null);
                //}
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion
}
#endregion
```

Comment: It would really help if you could post *short* but complete examples in the future. You've given us nearly 200 lines of code, without even showing which line is reporting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the reason - but you should maintain the generic parameter constraints on the `Person<T>` class. So add the `where T : new()` to the `Person<T>` class.

**EDIT**

After compiling your code, I get the error:

> Error 1   'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Reflection.ObjectFactory' SomeClass.cs    67  18  Reflection

This error is solved by the addition of the `where` clause I mentioned above. After that point, I get no compilation errors.

Comment: Ah right, so is it not possible to have my class Person to inherit from ObjectFactory? The reason I want it to is because it caches any instantiated types (I am working on a generic approach to saving, deleting and loading objects) and performs other operations. The main reason I want it to inherit is because the ObjectFactory class creates instances of other classes quicker than using Activator.CreateInstance<>.

Comment: Your `Person` class *can* inherit from `ObjectFactory`, but because it is passing it's generic parameter type to the `ObjectFactory`, it must have matching constraints. Simply adding the `new()` constraint should solve the issue (so far as I can see).

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much, I can progress with my little side project now, thanks again :)